# Index numpy array by other array as indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to take array

```
a = [1,5,4,5,7,8,9,8,4,13,43,42]
```

and array

```
b = [3,5,6,2,7]
```

And I want b to be the indexes in a, e.g. a new array that is

```
[a[b[0]], a[b[1]], a[b[2]], a[b[3]] ...]
```

So the values in b are indexes into a.
And there are 500k entries in a and 500k in b (approximately).
Is there a fast way to kick in all cores in numpy to do this?
I already do it just fine in for loops and it is sloooooooowwwwww.

Edit to clarify.  The solution has to work for 2D and 3D arrays.
so maybe

```
b = [(2,3), (5,4), (1,2), (1,0)]
```

and we want

```
c = [a[b[0], a[b[1], ...]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by writing a C extension to numpy called Tensor Weighted Interpolative Transfer, in order to get speed and multi-threading. In pure python it is 3 seconds per 200x100x3 image scale and fade across, and in multi-threaded C with 8 cores is 0.5 milliseconds for the same operation.

The core C code ended up being like

```
t2[dstidxs2[i2] + doff1] += t1[srcidxs2[i2] + soff1] * w1 * ws2[i2];
```

Where the doff1 is the offset in the destination array etc. The w1 and ws2 are the interpolated weights.
All the code is ultra optimized in C for speed. (not code size or maintainability)

All code is available on https://github.com/RMKeene/twit and on PyPI.

I expect furthur optimization in the future such as special cases if all weights are 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Not saying it is fast, but the numpy way would simply be:

```
a[b]
```

outputs:

> array([5, 8, 9, 4, 8])

Comment: Elegant answer!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in NumPy using [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). As [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845653/4909228) pointed out, in the 1-D case, you would simply write:

```
a[b]
```

and that is equivalent to:

```
[a[b[x]] for x in range(b.shape[0])]
```

In higher-dimensional cases, however, you need to have separate lists for each dimension of the indices. Which means, you can't do:

```
a = np.random.randn(7, 8, 9)  # 3D array
b = [(2, 3, 0), (5, 4, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 0, 3)]
print(a[b])  # this is incorrect
```

but you can do:

```
b0, b1, b2 = zip(*b)
print(a[b0, b1, b2])
```

you can also use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
print(np.take(a, b))
```